# Python Numpy: ValueError: shapes (200,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy

I have two python numpy arrays; a1, and W2, and I want to make a numpy dot product:

```
z2 = a1.dot(W2)
```

Shape of a1 array is (200,2), and shape of W2 array is (1, 2). Why I encounter the error `ValueError: shapes (200,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)`?

Comment: Well, according to matrix-multiplication, it would be do elementwise multiplications between the last axis of first array with the first axis of second array, right? With that consideration, the error makes sense.

Comment: What may I do to fix this reasonable error?

Comment: `a1.dot(W2.T)` or `a1.dot(W2.ravel())`

Comment: you need to transpose the second matrix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a misunderstanding of how matrix multiplication works in Mathematics rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplication condition is not valid in this case `a1*w2`.
The rows of `w2` should equal to the columns of `a1`!